# Looking up a list of lists to a table and writing a new list of lists - R

Tags: r

I am new to R and Stackoverflow. Having trawled through Stackoverflow, I can't find anything to help me.

I have a data frame of items and a list of lists representing the combinations in which suppliers products can be grouped together:

Date frame:

```
Item Barcode Source    SourceNum
  <int>   <int> <chr>         <int>
1     1     100 Supplier1         1
2     2     101 Supplier1         1
3     3     102 Supplier2         2
4     4     103 Supplier2         2
```

List of lists (a) derived by using listParts(2) function:

```
[1] (1,2)
[1] (1)(2)
```

I need to take each list, lookup the items represented by those SourceNums and build a list of the item barcodes.

For example:

a[1] of (1,2) must look up against column SourceNum and read Barcode and save this to a list of barcodes so that output is something like:

```
b[1] (100,101,102,103)
b[2] (100,101),(102,103)
```

The number of sources needs to be a variable as it is not always 2.

My end output is to get a list of items with their dimensions from a second table (df2) as below:

```
         Code `Length (cm)` `Height (cm)` `Width (cm)` `Volume (cm3)`
  <int>         <int>         <int>        <int>          <int>
1   100            15            20           20           6000
2   101            45            45            4           8100
3   102            25            28            5           3500
4   103            30            30           25          22500
```

So for b[1] I need a list of 1 object of 4 items (because the 4 items are listed together in 1 list), but each item also needs to have 3 elements reading length, height, width from this table. 
b[2] should be a list of 2 objects of 2 items each, also with each item with length, height, width.

Comment: please tell us which packages you are using. listparts is not a base function

Comment: Do you mean this? `library(partitions);
a_list <- listParts(2);
lapply(a_list, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) paste(lapply(y, function(z) 
  paste(df$Barcode[df$SourceNum==z], collapse=",")),collapse=",")))`

Comment: @Prem  That's perfect thanks so much! I'm just trying to understand how I'd use that output - I'm still getting used to the lists functions and syntax. I've saved your code to b where b[2] returns: 
[[2]]
[[2]]$`1`
[1] "100,101"

[[2]]$`2`
[1] "102,103"

If I need to look up the cost of these items from df2$costprice for example, how would I use the output to compare to df2$costprice?

Comment: Another `lapply` can be handy in this case and for that you need not concatenate barcode using `,` which has been done using `paste` command. I would recommend updating your post with `df2` detail and also the final desired output sample so that we can guide you in right direction.

Comment: I have updated the post. I hope this makes sense. I basically need to group together the items and their dimensions given the different combinations in which they can present themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways this can be done.

```
library('tidyverse')
library('partitions')

df <- read_table2('Item Barcode Source    SourceNum
1     100 Supplier1         1
2     101 Supplier1         1
3     102 Supplier2         2
4     103 Supplier2         2')

list_parts <- listParts(2)
```

The first way is to flatten the list and `map` each of the `SourceNum`s to the corresponding `Barcode`s. Then recreate the original structure using `relist`.

```
barcodes <- list_parts %>%
  unlist %>%
  map(~df$Barcode[df$SourceNum == .]) %>%
  relist(list_parts)

str(barcodes)
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ 1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 100 101
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 102 103
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "equivalence"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ 1:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 100 101
#>   ..$ 2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 102 103
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "equivalence"
```

The other way is to use nested `map`s.

```
barcodes <- listParts(2) %>%
  map(map, map, ~df$Barcode[df$SourceNum == .])

str(barcodes)
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ 1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 100 101
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 102 103
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ 1:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 100 101
#>   ..$ 2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2] 102 103
```

Comment: Thanks so much I think it's basically there! How can the output of barcodes[1] be a single list? Right now it is further split into 2 lists? So barcodes[1] should give (100,101,102,103). Currently I'll need to drill down another level?

Comment: Just need to unlist the correct level. barcodes <- listParts(2) %>%
  map(map, map, ~df$Barcode[df$SourceNum == .]) %>%
  map(map, unlist)

Comment: To give you an understanding of my end goal I have updated the post. I hope this makes sense. I basically need to group together the items and their dimensions given the different combinations in which they can present themselves.